# Linuxのスクリプトで特定の文字列以前の文字を取得、もしくは以降の文字以降を削除

Tags: linux, shellscript

ログの収集で正規表現を使って、`\`(バックスラッシュ)よりも前の文字列(下記の場合だと`stat/about`)を取得したいと考えています。

置換は分かるのですが、その部分だけ抜き取る正規表現の書き方がわかりません。
どうかご教授いただけませんでしょうか。

```
stat/about\,\form
posts/6\,\format\
```

Comment: `posts/6\,\format\ ` の場合は `posts/6` だけを取得したいということでよろしいでしょうか？ それとも `posts/6` と `format` の両方を抽出したいのでしょうか？

Comment: `posts/6\`,`\format\` の場合は `posts/6` だけを取得したいという意図でした！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cut コマンドを使う方法もあります(正規表現は使っていませんが…)。

```
$ echo 'stat/about\,\form' | cut -d\\ -f1
stat/about
```

その他、GNU grep では以下の様になります。

```
$ echo 'stat/about\,\form' | grep -Po '^.*?(?=\\.*)'
stat/about
```

Answer (score 3):

逆に「バックスラッシュとそれ以後を消す」と考えて、そこの部分を正規表現でマッチさせて、空文字に置換しては？

```
sed -e 's/\\.*//'
```

バックスラッシュが複数あるときは複数取り出したい、というなら、awkでフィールド区切り文字をバックスラッシュにすればいいかと。

Comment: 意図を汲んで頂き、有り難うございます。こちらで無事解決出来ました！

Answer (score 0):

awk を使う方法をご紹介します。

```
$ awk -F '\' '{print $1}' data.txt
stat/about
posts/6
```

`-F '\'` は区切り文字を「\」と指定します。
`{print $1}` は 区切り文字で分割した 1番目の値を表示します。
data.txt は 変換前のテキストデータです。

標準入力から読み込む場合は

```
$ echo 'stat/about\,\form' | awk -F '\' '{print $1}'
stat/about

$ cat data.txt | awk -F '\' '{print $1}'
stat/about
posts/6
```

こうなります。

Answer (score 0):

`grep` でマッチした部分だけ出力、というのがぱっと浮かんだ方法です。

```sh
$ cat <<'EOF' | grep -o '^[^\\]*'
stat/about\,\form
posts/6\,\format\
EOF

stat/about
posts/6


$ echo 'stat/about\,\form' | grep -o '^[^\\]*'

stat/about
```